# Как использовать Vuex в разделенных файлах Vue в Laravel Mix?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

В Laravel mix используется webpack для сборки модулей. У меня есть два входных файла: header.js и main.js. Они должны (по задумке) использовать общее состояние Vuex Store из файла store.js.

Файл store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({    
    state: {
        isVisible: true
    },
    mutations: {
        show: state => state.isVisible = true,
        hide: state => state.isVisible = false
    }    
})
```

А в файлах main.js и header.js подключаю `import store from './store';` Но ведут они себя странно, header.js работает исправно, а main.js ругается на Vuex: `[vuex] already installed. Vue.use(Vuex) should be called only once.` и дальше соответственно никак нельзя обратиться к `$store`.

Кстати файлы на странице подключены в таком порядке:

```
<!--...-->
<body>
    <script src="header.js"></script>
    <!--...-->
    <script src="main.js"></script>
```

Поправьте меня, если я туплю, и подскажите пожалуйста как сделать правильно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Импортируешь два раза одно и то же, поэтому и ругается, проимпортируй зависимость в bootstrap.js